# Firefox glitching CSS transistions

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

**_ UPDATE _**

OK, this is what I have discovered about Firefox: Glitching can happen if you set transition states to activate on css:hover (in my case) for a one div then set further transition states to elements inside that container.

I need to work out a work around. As I want certain elements to be activated once your in that area of the div rather then having to hover directly over text (smaller capture area).

**_ OLD _**
I'm unable to find the cause of this issue, and it's bugging me. Reading some articles on the net in regards to this issue works just fine, but mine doesn't (in Firefox). And I'm having trouble with `js fiddle` to make a quick test file.

As you click on the `login` input, if it's still transitioning and you click on the input box, and activate the next transition, its jumps/glitches are not shown in `Chrome` or `IE 10`. Is there any software that emulates different `IE` versions?

Can anyone see the glitching or is it just me?

Solved see below.

Answer (score 1):

In ie10 isn't there a "Compatibility View" in the Developer Tools? You can switch that to different Browser Modes (ie9, ie8).

Comment: any idea why the page is glitching in firefox?

Comment: Maybe you could try not transitioning "all" the properties; just specific ones you need. Maybe you could narrow down what's causing probs in FF. And yes, FF seems a bit jumpy.

Comment: ok will hash out some code see what happens is this a firefox bug that anyone else has come across? thanks adam